# downloaded the petcare application, help with running it

Tags: java, spring, maven-2, petcare

I downloaded spring's petcare application from their svn repository.

How do I go about loading in an editor and running it?

It has a pom.xml file, and I see references to eclipse.

I downloaded eclipse, but I guess I need some sort of plugin to open it?

Is there a readme file that I missed that details on how to run this sample application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The petcare sample application that can be accessed in the **[Spring Samples SVN repository](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/petcare/trunk)** is **directly** importable & runnable with **[SpringSource Tool Suite](http://www.springsource.com/products/sts)**. This is the easiest and most straight forward way, it doesn't require any Maven knowledge nor specific Maven plugin and STS is the best ready to use Spring environment you can get (which thus provides the best user experience).

Answer (score 3):

You should install the M2Eclipse plugin for Eclipse in order to get Maven2 support in Eclipse.

http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/

Maven2 is definitely worth your time to learn if you are a serious Java developer.

Comment: just find it odd why a sample application would require a plugin like that :) (with no readme file to boot!)

Comment: pom.xml definitely indicates maven.  The thing is, maven handles, among other things, dependency management (like dependent jar files).  When you use it, you can distribute just your source code and not have to have people go on these wild goose chases for figuring out what dependencies you have.

It's a bit of a chore, but, it is worth your effort to use.

Comment: understood, it sounds great.  It is just that I want to get this sample up and running, not learn maven at this point! hope you can understand from a newbies perspective!

Comment: Well you don't need to learn maven, you just need to know the commands to build the project. Just like if this application was using Ant for it's build system - you wouldn't need to learn Ant completely, just the commands to build the project. 

Loading up the source code in your IDE isn't really the responsibility of the build system. Maven just happens to have a helpful plugin that can help with this. You *could* do it by hand.

Comment: that's true matt b and thanks for clarifying.  As you indicated, I meant "get a rudimentary knowlege of how to run some tasks".  mvn eclipse:eclipse is an especially good one, but you are right, one could make the IDE understand the project by hand withou using maven.  The info you need to do that is in the pom.xml itself.  You could browse ibilio or other maven repositories to get the jar files directly (assuming there are dependencies).